# Get subcategories names and its product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am having a category name 'package', and a few sub-categories attached to it, in each sub categories, I a having several products

Package
--SubCat1
----product1
----product2
--SubCat2
----product1
----product2

etc

I want to display in a comboBox the sub-categories, and according from the choice of the subcategory its products

1. How can I get all the sub categories from the parent ( package)
2. How to get the products from the sub categories selected ?

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question, and ususally I do not answer with just a plugin raccomandation, but in this case -  it will be too elaborated and long to to reply here ..

so - I have been using a great little plugin that does just what you need , and with a little tweaking, you will get the wanted result .
Also, you could have a look inside it´s rather simple code and see exactly how it is done ...

Plugin Name : [Category Ajax Chain Select](http://www.peterjharrison.me/2011/11/category-ajax-chain-select-wordpress-plugin-2/)